# About the set of $x$ values at which the Taylor series of $f(x)$ converges to $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)$ be a function (for simplicity, let us assume that it is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and infinitely differentiable), and $T$ the Taylor series of $f$ at $x=a$, with  interval of convergence $I$. Let $S\subseteq I$ be the subset of $x$ values at which $T(x)$ converges to $f(x)$. My question is: what does the set $S$ look like? For example, is it always an interval centered at $x=a$ ? Or is it always a disjoint union of disconnected intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S $  could be really wild. The Taylor series only depends on the beaviour of $f $ around $a .$ For instance let $g $ be some function and put 
$$
f (x)=\begin {cases} e^{-1/t^2},&\ -.1 <x <.1\\ g (x),&\ |x|\geq.1\end {cases}
$$
For $a=0$ we have  $T (x)=0$, so $I=\mathbb R$, and $S=\{t:\ g (t)=0\}. $ Now play with $g $ (it doesn't even have to be continuous!).